# Failed To Compile Error When Run LibGdx Project

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am porting my game which is developed in Libgdx Platform.Now i am trying to port in IOS.When i run my project it getting me this error :-

Error MT5103: Failed to compile the file '/var/folders/lc/_tfkdygx19gf9b1rg1ycb3rm0000gn/T/tmp14641e8e.tmp/main.i386.m'. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (MT5103)

Please let me know how can i resolve it.I have already purchase mono touch license.

If I am using it -nosymbolstrip -nostrip -cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/libs/ios -L${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/ikvm/bin -likvm-natives -lgdx -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/libgdx.a -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/ikvm/bin/libikvm-natives.a" "-v -v -v" then it getting me this error

Error MT0010: Could not parse the command line arguments: Cannot bundle unregistered option '- '. (MT0010) (demoProject-ios)

Getting This Error :-

Copied /var/folders/lc/_tfkdygx19gf9b1rg1ycb3rm0000gn/T/tmp3e42cb58.tmp/libObjectAL.dll to /Users/rishabhagrawal/Desktop/spidy 3s2 2/demoProject-ios/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/demoProjectios.app/libObjectAL.dll
Linking assembly /Users/rishabhagrawal/Desktop/spidy 3s2 2/demoProject-ios/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/iosgame.exe into /Users/rishabhagrawal/Desktop/spidy 3s2 2/demoProject-ios/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/demoProjectios.app
error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Array index is out of range.
--- inner exception
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
  at Mono.Cecil.Signatures.SignatureWriter.Write (NamedArg na, Mono.Cecil.Binary.MemoryBinaryWriter writer) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.Signatures.SignatureWriter.Write (Mono.Cecil.Signatures.CustomAttrib ca, Mono.Cecil.MethodReference ctor, Mono.Cecil.Binary.MemoryBinaryWriter writer) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.Signatures.SignatureWriter.CompressCustomAttribute (Mono.Cecil.Signatures.CustomAttrib ca, Mono.Cecil.MethodReference ctor, Mono.Cecil.Binary.MemoryBinaryWriter writer) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.Signatures.SignatureWriter.AddCustomAttribute (Mono.Cecil.Signatures.CustomAttrib ca, Mono.Cecil.MethodReference ctor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionWriter.VisitCustomAttributeCollection (Mono.Cecil.CustomAttributeCollection customAttrs) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionWriter.TerminateModuleDefinition (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.StructureWriter.TerminateAssemblyDefinition (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Accept (IReflectionStructureVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyFactory.WriteAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm, System.IO.BinaryWriter bw) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyFactory.SaveAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm, System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyFactory.SaveAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition asm, System.String file) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.OutputAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.ProcessAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0

### at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoTouch.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context, System.Collections.Generic.List`1& assemblies) [0x00000] in :0

at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoTouch.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context, System.Collections.Generic.List`1& assemblies) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MTouch.LinkAssemblies (System.String main, System.Collections.Generic.List`1& assemblies, Boolean include_debug_info) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MTouch.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MTouch.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Comment: As mentioned in the error message please file a bug report with a test case (so it can be reproduced) and state the versions numbers of the products. Few error message asks for this - but when they do it's because something unexpected occurred (and it's unlikely that previous/future solutions to MT5103 will be the same).

Comment: The "-v -v -v" should not be quoted together. It should be `-v -v -v` added to the command-line.

Comment: when i use it like 

-nosymbolstrip -nostrip -cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/libs/ios -L${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/ikvm/bin -likvm-natives -lgdx -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/libgdx.a -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/ikvm/bin/libikvm-natives.a" -nosymbolstrip -nostrip -cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/libs/ios -L${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/ikvm/bin -likvm-natives -lgdx -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/libgdx.a -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libs/ios/ikvm/bin/libikvm-natives.a" -v -v -v

Then giving me this error. Error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Array index is out of range. (MT2001)

Comment: The point of adding `-v -v -v` to get extra build time information. However it's not helpful if you do not give us the **full** build log. Please **file** a bug report and attach the **full** build log.

Comment: update error on question